# How do I print an image in my website without the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone please show me how to print an image in my web-page leaving behind the text and the HTML surrounding the image?

In my website the is a page that displays an image and it allows the users to print the image via a

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print()">PRINT</a>
```

link. The problem is the printed page comes with some HTML and some texts from the website. But I only want the image. Is there a way to get only the image and avoid everything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use CSS media query for that, e.g:

```
@media print {
    body *:not(img) {display:none;}
}
```

- `img` or any more specific selector targeting the image you wish to print.

[### -DEMO jsFiddle-](https://jsfiddle.net/rj7sq4c7/)

Comment: When using this, you just need to place the printable image directly within the body, if it's inside of another element, it will be hidden as well along that element.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do instead of calling the window.print directly is keep a hidden `div` in the bottom of the page.
As soon as user click of the print button, dynamically add an image in the hidden div.Then just print the contents of the hidden div. Something like this in a function on click of the button,

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById("idOfYourHiddenDiv").innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
```

Comment: Since you have not added any html markup, I have just provided an outline~